# How to consume XML from REST API to SQL for a SharePoint Site

Tags: c#, xml, rest, sharepoint, ssis

I am pulling list items from a SharePoint site using REST API. The XMLs I receive back are with more than 1 namespaces. I am cleaning these out using an XSLT file. However, since the xmls returned are of the format:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <feed xml:base="https://thomasmorestudent17.sharepoint.com/sites/devtest/_api/"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<id>b82076e4-3e36-4b09-bbed-3d14e0bf948f</id> 
<title /> 
<updated>2014-03-19T10:21:14Z</updated> 
<entry>
<id>https://thomasmorestudent17.sharepoint.com/sites/devtest/_api/Web/Lists(guid'ab8811c5-0d39-457c-8fd1-c15a45c78f89')/files('Aanleiding en achtergrond van het project.docx')</id> 
<category term="MS.FileServices.File" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
<link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'ab8811c5-0d39-457c-8fd1-c15a45c78f89')/files('Aanleiding%20en%20achtergrond%20van%20het%20project.docx')" /> 
<title /> 
<updated>2014-03-19T10:21:14Z</updated> 
<author>
   <name /> 
</author>
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
   <d:CreatedBy m:type="MS.FileServices.UserInformation">
        <d:Id>9</d:Id> 
        <d:Name>Thomas More</d:Name> 
    </d:CreatedBy>
  <d:ETag>"{ECAEE072-FEDD-4FF6-8A27-1EFF131B0064},1"</d:ETag> 
  <d:Id>Aanleiding en achtergrond van het project.docx</d:Id> 
    <d:LastModifiedBy m:type="MS.FileServices.UserInformation">
        <d:Id>9</d:Id> 
        <d:Name>Thomas More</d:Name> 
    </d:LastModifiedBy>
    <d:Name>Aanleiding en achtergrond van het project.docx</d:Name> 
    <d:Size m:type="Edm.Int32">21616</d:Size> 
    <d:TimeCreated m:type="Edm.DateTime">2014-03-14T17:24:25Z</d:TimeCreated> 
    <d:TimeLastModified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2014-03-14T17:24:25Z</d:TimeLastModified> 
    <d:Url>/sites/devtest/Shared Documents/Aanleiding en achtergrond van het project.docx</d:Url> 
 </m:properties>
```

How do I consume this so that I can input the valus into SQL using C#.net?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the Sharepoint CSOM (Client Object Model) library instead of working directly with the REST API. It is a wrapper around the REST API that will handle all of the XML for you, so you can work directly with C# objects. You can then populate your Entity Framework entities or SQL inserts from those objects.

Here is a link to get you started:

[How to: Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. CSOM method does not work for large lists. When the list has more that 5000 items, the method times out.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, you mentioned importing the XML into SQL via C#. Is using C# a requirement or can you use SSIS. If you have transformed the XML to remove multi-namespace XML then using the XML Source in SSIS would make the import to SQL fairly straight forward and wouldn't require custom coding of C#.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. I tried doing this method. But the XML after removal of namespace is not a format that can be read by SSIS - XML Source